# to change url structure for blog posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to add parent to posts in wordpress, for that I need to change the permalinks, but I am not able to figure it out.

for e.g. if the current url is [www.abcd.com/postname](http://www.abcd.com/postname)

I want it like this, [www.abcd.com/posts/postname](http://www.abcd.com/posts/postname)

Thank you in advance

Comment: this is solved. thanks

Comment: Great, I have shared the answer so that it helps others.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to visit the **Settings » Permalinks** page in your WordPress admin. There you need to click on the ‘custom structure’ option under the common settings area.

Next, you need to add `/%category%/%postname%/` in the field next to the custom structure.

I have used `/%category%/` just as an example. Change it accordingly.